# jQuery script for choosing rating

Tags: jquery, html, css

I write jQuery scripts for choosing rating
This is HTML code

```
<div class="rating clearfix">
<div class="stars">
    <div class="stars_width"></div>
</div>
<input id="rating-input" type="hidden" value="8">
<input id="article-id" type="hidden" value="">
</div>
```

jQuery script

```
function starsMouseMove(n, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var i = $el.offset().left,
        t = Math.floor((n.pageX - i)),
        w;
    if (t > 0 && t < 20) {
        w = 20;
    } else if (t >= 20 && t < 40) {
        w = 40;
    } else if (t >= 40 && t < 60) {
        w = 60;
    } else if (t >= 60 && t < 80) {
        w = 80;
    } else if (t >= 80 && t <= 100) {
        w = 100;
    }
    $(".stars_width", $el).css("width", w + "%");
};

function starsSelect(n, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var i = $el.offset().left,
        t = Math.floor((n.pageX - i)),
        w;
    if (t > 0 && t < 20) {
        w = 20;
    } else if (t >= 20 && t < 40) {
        w = 40;
    } else if (t >= 40 && t < 60) {
        w = 60;
    } else if (t >= 60 && t < 80) {
        w = 80;
    } else if (t >= 80 && t <= 100) {
        w = 100;
    }
    $(".stars_width", $el).css("width", w + "%");
    $el.parent().find('#rating-input').val(w / 10);
};

$(".stars_width").css("width", $("#rating-input").val() * 20 + "%");  
$('.stars').hover(function(e) {
    starsMouseMove(e, this);
}, function(e){
    $(".stars_width").css("width", $("#rating-input").val() * 20 + "%"); 
});

$('.stars').click(function(e) {
    starsSelect(e, this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tu8v3cnt/14/

I need to change rating on mouse moving over `$('.stars')` but save it only after click. If rating was not chosen (clicked), I need to back a default value.
But I have a problem here, script works on `click` properly, but it doesn't work on `hover` the right way. How can I fix it?
And I have duplicated code in two function but I don't know how to write script without it.

Comment: can store initial value on the element using `jQuery.data()` then retrieve it in mouseleave part of `hover`

Comment: definitely. but the first problem is `hover` doesn''t work properly.

Comment: personally I would find the whole thing a lot simpler with 5 spans ..one for each star, then set background position for each using classes. Would be less code and don't have to calculate widths

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: this is more how I would approach  http://jsfiddle.net/g46afg64/ If you remove my margins it will work better - was just a rough proof of concept

Answer (score 2):

Using a mousemove function seems to do the trick. For saving, it will only save when you click. If you mean saving the rating to **article-id** then change all the **rating-input** in the code to **article-id**

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/w3k31quz/

**Code**

```
function starsMouseMove(n, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        var i = $el.offset().left,
            t = Math.floor((n.pageX - i)),
            w;
        if (t > 0 && t < 20) {
            w = 20;
            $("#rating-input").val("1")
        } else if (t >= 20 && t < 40) {
            w = 40;
            $("#rating-input").val("2")
        } else if (t >= 40 && t < 60) {
            w = 60;
            $("#rating-input").val("3")
        } else if (t >= 60 && t < 80) {
            w = 80;
            $("#rating-input").val("4")
        } else if (t >= 80 && t <= 100) {
            w = 100;
            $("#rating-input").val("5")
        }
        $(".stars_width", $el).css("width", w + "%");
    };



    $(".stars_width").css("width", $("#rating-input").val() * 20 + "%");  
    $('.stars').mousemove(function(e) {
        starsMouseMove(e, this);
    });

    $('.stars').click(function(e) {
        alert($("#rating-input").val())
    });
```

A shorthand of the Code can be to divide **w** with **20**

```
$("#rating-input").val(w / 20);
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/xtkfxbmn/

Comment: Your solution works the other way I need. I needed to change rating on mouse moving over $('.stars') but save it only after click. If rating was not chosen (clicked), I need to back a default value. So I used script from a comment above.